# Performance issue when reloading tableview section

Tags: ios, performance, cocoa-touch, uitableview, instruments

When new data is received by my app, a notification is sent out and received by my view controller. The view controller then reloads one of the sections of its tableview. This typically takes just 40ms or so.

However, if I have pushed another view, the notifications are still processed by the original controller but the reload of the tableview takes about 10-20x longer.

I can certainly work on improving my tableview performance, but first I need to understand what is causing this. Would also appreciate some help using Instruments on how to debug this myself. So far I have run the 'Time Profiler' instrument and it looks like most of the effort is expended in system method, '`[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutIfNeeded]`'. This doesn't mean much to me.

Comment: Are you still calling reloadSections:withRowAnimation: on the table view when that controller is not on screen?

Comment: The controller is still responding to those notifications in its normal way, yes. The idea being that if something changes while the user is elsewhere, the tableview updates.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea, when the view is not on the screen. Maybe you could separate the updating of the data source (which would be done by the notification) from the updating of the table view, and only do the latter if the view is on screen.

Comment: That might help. Except I would have to then manually reload in viewWillAppear, which would break some animations (e.g. the selected cell). I suppose this will happen anyway if the data happens to update while off screen. I think if I were to go this route I might just stop checking for updates altogether when not on the main controller. Mostly i'm interested in why the same operation takes a fraction of the time when on screen, though.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need to be updating UI on an element that isn't onscreen. UI updates will take place in the main thread, which will negatively impact user experience.

Updating your data source (in a background thread) should be more then adequate, and then you can update the tableview when it is next shown to the user.

Comment: If that's the approach I take I think I would just unsubscribe from the notifications entirely on disappear and re-subscribe on appear. Otherwise I have to code around some edge cases. But I would like to understand the root cause most of all - why would the same method take so much longer when the view is off screen vs on screen.

Comment: I would guess it's because when the view is off screen the main thread is occupied with handling user interactions and doing UI updates on the displayed view, and your code is also trying to run in the main thread. Can't tell without seeing it, though.